# Exclude laravel route using wildcard

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs

How to exclude a path for my front end app? Like I'm using react and everything after dashboard should serve react router not laravel route.

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'AppController@getApp');
```

Above is my route in web/route.php

With that I'm only able to use example.com/dashboard but when I hit example.com/dashboard/analytic it still used laravel route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try routing any request done to your dashboard like so:

```
Route::any('/dashboard/{path?}', 'AppController@getApp')->where("path", ".+");
```

Comment: where is my dashboard prefix? it will hit react router if only user hit example.com/dashboard/something

Comment: I've changed the route to have the dashboard prefix. This uses an optional route parameter, whould should catch `/dashboard` or any variation of it, like `/dashboard/foo`. More information on optional route arguments can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-optional-parameters